# JBoss WildFly: Starts but can't connect?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I just configured JBoss WildFly. It is running and it is accessible from the same machine, everything is working fine...

My problem is that it is not accessible from another system (I mean in a network, the server (hosted machine) URL can't access from another system).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

By default jboss/wildfly binding to localhost, if you want change this, you can execute:

```
standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0
```

listen on all IP addresses of the machine (if multihomed)

Another alternative is configure in `standalone.xml` the interfaces section.

Change:

```
<interfaces>
  <interface name="management">
   <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
  </interface>
  <interface name="public">
   <inet-address value="127.0.0.1"/>
  </interface>
</interfaces>
```

to:

```
<interfaces>
  <interface name="management">
   <!-- Use the IPv4 wildcard address -->
   <any-ipv4-address/>
  </interface>
  <interface name="public">
   <!-- Use the IPv4 wildcard address -->
   <any-ipv4-address/>
  </interface>
</interfaces>
```

**Ref:**

- [WildFly - Interfaces and ports](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Interfaces+and+ports)
- [WildFly - Command line parameters](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Command+line+parameters)

**UPDATE**

From Wildfly 8 `<any-ipv4-address/>` was [deprecated](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-4148?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) and remove in Wildfly 9, then if you are in 9.x or higher use `<any-address/>`.

> Deprecated. In the absence of `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`, the
>   JVM cannot be instructed to bind a socket to all IPv4 addresses, but
>   only to IPv4 addresses, so the intended semantic cannot be obtained
>   via this setting alone. Since using `any-addressType` and setting
>   `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` provides the same effect, this
>   `any-ipv4-addressType` will be removed in a future release.

Eg:

```
<interface name="global">
   <!-- Use the wildcard address -->
   <any-address/>
</interface>
```

Comment: Thank you ! For the standalone.xml in Wildfly 9.0.1 its :
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:put.your.ip.here}"/>
<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:put.your.ip.here}"/>

Comment: This does not work any more for Wildfly 9.0.2+. See the answer of @bkomac below

Comment: great update, any-address was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 22):

The `<any-ipv4-address/>` is deprecated in WF 9, use:

```
 ...   
    <interface name="management">
       <any-address/>
    </interface>
 ...
```

Comment: And since 9.0.2 '<any-ipv4-address/>' will produce a error while starting wildfly ... :-o

Answer (score 4):

(I summary 2 answers for a working solution)
I am using WildFly 10.0.0.Final - lastest version at writing time. Look for file `standalone.xml` like this:
On Windows

```
C:\tools\wildfly-10.0.0.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml
```

Or Linux, like this:

```
/home/vyhn.net/wildfly-servlet-10.0.0.Final/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
```

edit become to:

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <!-- Allow all external IP -->
        <any-address/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <!-- Allow all external IP -->
    <any-address/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

Then go to:

```
http://your_domain:9990/error/index.html
```

(port `9990` is default HTTP port, if you use firewall or iptables, remember open port `9990`)
For example:

```
http://vyhn.net:9990/error/index.html
```

You will see it works successful.
Lastest reference (WildFly 10): https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Interfaces+and+ports

Answer (score 3):

**Don't forget the firewall!**

If you fixed the binding addresses and still can not connect to JBoss, try to work around the server's firewall.

To stop the firewall on Linux **RHEL** use this command:

```
/etc/init.d/iptables stop
```

**An update (April 2018):**

On **RHEL7**, where **firewalld** is used (rather than iptables), you may use:

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

or open the specific Jboss/Wildfly ports (e.g. 8080/9990) with these  two commands:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use -b 0.0.0.0 to allow access regardless of the public ip assigned, e.g. for computers getting dynamic IP (using DHCP), I find this a convenient way.

**Eclipse users**: Beware that in Server configuration, the "Host name:" input is used to set the "-b" program argument, overriding your modifications!