# Phonegap seems to block network connections

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-developer-app

I'm creating a simple cross-platform app using Phonegap-CLI (v5.4.0) and Phonegap-developer-app (Android and iOS, both are up to date). In my app I'm trying to call a REST-Interface I implemented, I use jQuery AJAX to do so. Unfortunately those calls seem not to work, I don't see any incoming calls in my console. (REST-Interface is running locally on my machine.) However, I do know that my REST-Interface works fine, because I can call the REST-Interface correctly using the IntelliJ-testing-tool.

My `index.html` looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <!-- Latest minified version -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
        <!--Optional theme-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"></link>
        <title>MyApp</title>
    </head>
    <body class="noscroll">

        <div class="app">

            <!-- ... -->
            <div class="row fullWidth" style="height:70px;">
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-10"><button id="logInBtn" class="fillParent emphSmall">Login</button></div>
                <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/customFunctions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){

            $("#logInBtn").on("click", function (){
                alert("beginning ajax call");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    Accept: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "http://<ip>:8080/myApp/rest/Something",
                    success: function(){
                        alert("works!")

                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("doesn't work!");
                    }
                });

            });

        }, true);

        /*app.initialize();*/
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is how my `config.xml` looks like. It's the default file that was generated while creating the project:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="my.app.identifier" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>hibou</name>
<description>
    Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
    PhoneGap Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="orientation" value="default" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
<icon src="icon.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="blackberry" gap:state="hover" src="www/res/icon/blackberry/icon-80.png" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="www/res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
<icon gap:platform="webos" src="www/res/icon/webos/icon-64.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-48.png" />
<icon gap:platform="winphone" gap:role="background" src="www/res/icon/windows-phone/icon-173-tile.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="blackberry" src="www/res/screen/blackberry/screen-225.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="www/res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="www/res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>
```

With the above setup, i always get the "beginning" and "doesn't work"-alert. But since the AJAX-call works fine when I'm including it into some non-phonegap HTML-document and the call from my app doesn't even reach my REST-Interface, I'm assuming that it might be some problem with the phonegap-whitelist-plugin, but as you can see, it's already included into the `config.xml` and the `<access origin="*" />` tag should also permit all network connections. I already checked the Security-Policy meta-tag, but as far as I know, that shouldn't cause this problem either. After all, I don't know what could otherwise cause this error, so I'd really appreciate some help or a hint what I could miss here... **Thank you very much!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

My problem had nothing to do with the configuration of phonegap or any plugin. After reinstalling my application server some time ago, I simply [forgot to configure it to listen to all ip-adresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907323/jboss-wildfly-starts-but-cant-connect). Now everything works just fine.