# Unable to connect to an EC2 windows instance on port 8080

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I've created a free tier EC2 instance on AWS. I've opened inbound connections to this instance through security group. On EC2 instance, I'm able to access wildfly server and see it running/listening on port 127.0.0.1:8080. When I run netstat -ab command on EC2 instance I can see services listening on above IP address/port number combination. Could you please help me connect to this instance from my own machine? Please let me know if I should provide any additional info that would help troubleshoot the problem. Thanks in advance.

I've opened below inbound ports-

```
80      tcp 0.0.0.0/0
8080    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
22      tcp 0.0.0.0/0
23      tcp 0.0.0.0/0
3389    tcp 0.0.0.0/0
443     tcp 0.0.0.0/0
-1     icmp 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Did you check the Windows firewall? Which address do you use to connect remotely? The public dns name?

Comment: I've allowed all inbound traffic on port 8080 through windows firewall on EC2 instance. I'm using below address: xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080 to connect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service listens 127.0.0.1 which is not your network interface. Configure to listen to your instances private ip (10.x..) or 0.0.0.0 (all) instead

Comment: Could you please guide how can I achieve that? I've changed standalone.xml as below:   <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
and I've changed my /etc/hosts file with:    ::1  xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with the help of this post: [JBoss WildFly: Starts but can't connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907323/jboss-wildfly-starts-but-cant-connect)

I was almost there but had to change standalone.xml to listen to all ports as @Michel suggested. Below is my standalone.xml . Thank you all again for all the help.

Earlier standalone entry:

```
<interfaces> 
 <interface name="management"> 
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/> 
 </interface> 
 <interface name="public"> 
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/> 
 </interface> 
 <interface name="unsecure"> 
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.1}"/> 
 </interface> 
</interfaces>
```

Changed above to this:

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <!-- Use the IPv4 wildcard address -->
        <any-address/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <!-- Use the IPv4 wildcard address -->
        <any-address/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <!-- Use the IPv4 wildcard address -->
        <any-address/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
```