# Wildfly standalone starting over network not working

Tags: networking, jboss, wildfly, ip-address, wildfly-10

I'm working with Wildfly-10 Final, trying to start server on a debian machine, which is a remote server. It was starting with ./standalone.sh command, but was not showing up in the browser, i.e. x.x.x.x:8080, where x.x.x.x is the ip address of the server. I tried to ping x.x.x.x from (my home-computer) which is working. Then tried suggestion given here -
[JBoss WildFly: Starts but can't connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907323/jboss-wildfly-starts-but-cant-connect)

I tried both these -

```
  ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0
  ./standalone.sh -b x.x.x.x where x.x.x.x is the ipaddress
```

And then I tried with this -

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="x.x.x.x"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="x.x.x.x"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```

This is also not working.. This is a fresh debian machine, and i've not modified any iptables/firewall..

Debian version is 8.4, java version "1.8.0_101", wildfly-10.1.0.Final are the things I"m using.

What could be the problem? Any pointers will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I tried to check with netstat also

```
 sudo netstat -an | grep 8080
 tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:8080    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     


 netstat -an | grep 9990
 tcp        0      0 x.x.x.x:9990    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Which I guess tells it's running fine, but I'm still not getting. Some other things I'm checking - 
When I did wget http://x.x.x.x:8080, I got the index.html...
But when I did from my home-computer, I got this error:

```
 wget -v http://x.x.x.x:8080
 --2016-12-10 15:22:56--  http://x.x.x.x:8080/
Connecting to x.x.x.x:8080... failed: No route to host.
```

I'm beginning to suspect this could be more a problem of network/ip-address than of wildfly. Just for the sake of completeness, server lists two ip addresses when "ifconfig" is done, one for eth0, and another for eth1. Here x.x.x.x refers ip address linked to eth0.

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It was nothing to do with wildfly. My IPtables were blocking the incoming requests. So just edited ip tables rules for v4 by adding this line

-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT

And restarted server. It is working fine...