# How to connect to Port 8080 wildfly on Windows server 2012?

Tags: windows, server, wildfly

i want to connect to port 8080 from a wildfly.
This wilfly is on my windows server 2012.
I can connect to the ISS (80 Port).
I also made rules on the firewall for 8080, but it doesn't work?
Somebody knows how to fix it ? Or what did I forgot?

cheers Ciao

```html
2017-12-19 16:47:47,904 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.6.1.Final
2017-12-19 16:47:54,842 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.7.SP1
2017-12-19 16:47:55,688 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0049: Keycloak 3.4.1.Final (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) starting
2017-12-19 16:47:55,695 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Configured system properties:
 awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
 file.encoding = Cp1252
 file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
 file.separator = \
 java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
 java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
 java.class.path = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\jboss-modules.jar
 java.class.version = 52.0
 java.endorsed.dirs = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\endorsed
 java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
 java.home = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151
 java.io.tmpdir = C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\
 java.library.path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;.
 java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true
 java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
 java.runtime.version = 1.8.0_151-b12
 java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
 java.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
 java.specification.version = 1.8
 java.util.logging.manager = org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager
 java.vendor = Oracle Corporation
 java.vendor.url = http://java.oracle.com/
 java.vendor.url.bug = http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
 java.version = 1.8.0_151
 java.vm.info = mixed mode
 java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
 java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
 java.vm.specification.vendor = Oracle Corporation
 java.vm.specification.version = 1.8
 java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
 java.vm.version = 25.151-b12
 javax.management.builder.initial = org.jboss.as.jmx.PluggableMBeanServerBuilder
 javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
 javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
 javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
 javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
 javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
 javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
 javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
 javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
 javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory
 jboss.home.dir = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final
 jboss.host.name = win-3n1he53opph
 jboss.modules.dir = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\modules
 jboss.modules.system.pkgs = org.jboss.byteman
 jboss.node.name = win-3n1he53opph
 jboss.qualified.host.name = win-3n1he53opph
 jboss.server.base.dir = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\standalone
 jboss.server.config.dir = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\standalone\configuration
 jboss.server.data.dir = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\standalone\data
 jboss.server.deploy.dir = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\standalone\data\content
 jboss.server.log.dir = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\standalone\log
 jboss.server.name = win-3n1he53opph
 jboss.server.persist.config = true
 jboss.server.temp.dir = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\standalone\tmp
 line.separator = 

 logging.configuration = file:C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\standalone\configuration/logging.properties
 module.path = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\modules
 org.jboss.boot.log.file = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\standalone\log\server.log
 org.jboss.resolver.warning = true
 org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
 os.arch = x86
 os.name = Windows Server 2016
 os.version = 10.0
 path.separator = ;
 program.name = standalone.bat
 sun.arch.data.model = 32
 sun.boot.class.path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\classes
 sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin
 sun.cpu.endian = little
 sun.cpu.isalist = pentium_pro+mmx pentium_pro pentium+mmx pentium i486 i386 i86
 sun.desktop = windows
 sun.io.unicode.encoding = UnicodeLittle
 sun.java.command = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\jboss-modules.jar -mp C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\modules org.jboss.as.standalone -Djboss.home.dir=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final
 sun.java.launcher = SUN_STANDARD
 sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
 sun.management.compiler = HotSpot Client Compiler
 sun.os.patch.level = 
 sun.stderr.encoding = cp850
 sun.stdout.encoding = cp850
 user.country = US
 user.country.format = CH
 user.dir = C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\bin
 user.home = C:\Users\Administrator
 user.language = en
 user.language.format = fr
 user.name = Administrator
 user.script = 
 user.timezone = Europe/Berlin
 user.variant = 
2017-12-19 16:47:55,696 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) VM Arguments: -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\standalone\log\server.log -Dlogging.configuration=file:C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\standalone\configuration/logging.properties 
2017-12-19 16:48:10,596 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/core-service=management/management-interface=http-interface' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-12-19 16:48:10,643 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller.management-deprecated] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 5) WFLYCTL0028: Attribute 'security-realm' in the resource at address '/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https' is deprecated, and may be removed in future version. See the attribute description in the output of the read-resource-description operation to learn more about the deprecation.
2017-12-19 16:48:10,659 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 19) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.1.6.Final
2017-12-19 16:48:10,878 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0039: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
2017-12-19 16:48:10,925 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO version 3.5.4.Final
2017-12-19 16:48:11,034 WARN  [org.jboss.as.txn] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 43) WFLYTX0013: The node-identifier attribute on the /subsystem=transactions is set to the default value. This is a danger for environments running multiple servers. Please make sure the attribute value is unique.
2017-12-19 16:48:11,081 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 42) WFLYSEC0002: Activating Security Subsystem
2017-12-19 16:48:11,159 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) WFLYNAM0001: Activating Naming Subsystem
2017-12-19 16:48:11,175 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) WFLYCLINF0001: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
2017-12-19 16:48:11,190 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jaxrs] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) WFLYRS0016: RESTEasy version 3.0.24.Final
2017-12-19 16:48:10,972 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-2) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.5.4.Final
2017-12-19 16:48:11,690 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0009: Starting JCA Subsystem (WildFly/IronJacamar 1.4.6.Final)
2017-12-19 16:48:11,902 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) WFLYJCA0004: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.4)
2017-12-19 16:48:12,246 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.io] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 30) WFLYIO001: Worker 'default' has auto-configured to 2 core threads with 16 task threads based on your 1 available processors
2017-12-19 16:48:12,980 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.5.Final
2017-12-19 16:48:13,308 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSEC0001: Current PicketBox version=5.0.2.Final
2017-12-19 16:48:13,761 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYNAM0003: Starting Naming Service
2017-12-19 16:48:13,925 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0003: Undertow 1.4.18.Final starting
2017-12-19 16:48:13,925 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
2017-12-19 16:48:13,941 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) WFLYUT0014: Creating file handler for path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final/welcome-content' with options [directory-listing: 'false', follow-symlink: 'false', case-sensitive: 'true', safe-symlink-paths: '[]']
2017-12-19 16:48:13,972 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMAIL0001: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
2017-12-19 16:48:13,988 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0481: Strict pool slsb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 16 (per class), which is derived from thread worker pool sizing.
2017-12-19 16:48:14,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0482: Strict pool mdb-strict-max-pool is using a max instance size of 4 (per class), which is derived from the number of CPUs on this host.
2017-12-19 16:48:15,113 INFO  [org.jboss.as.patching] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYPAT0050: Keycloak cumulative patch ID is: base, one-off patches include: none
2017-12-19 16:48:15,160 WARN  [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYDM0111: Keystore C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\standalone\configuration\application.keystore not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed certificate for host localhost
2017-12-19 16:48:15,175 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0012: Started server default-server.
2017-12-19 16:48:15,175 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYDS0013: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\keycloak-3.4.1.Final\standalone\deployments
2017-12-19 16:48:15,269 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name: "keycloak-server.war")
2017-12-19 16:48:15,332 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0018: Host default-host starting
2017-12-19 16:48:15,519 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on 127.0.0.1:8080
2017-12-19 16:48:15,956 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYEJB0493: EJB subsystem suspension complete
2017-12-19 16:48:16,222 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener https listening on 127.0.0.1:8443
2017-12-19 16:48:16,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]
2017-12-19 16:48:16,519 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
2017-12-19 16:48:18,899 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final
2017-12-19 16:48:20,122 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 57) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container
2017-12-19 16:48:20,169 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYCLINF0002: Started sessions cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:20,169 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 56) WFLYCLINF0002: Started realms cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:20,185 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYCLINF0002: Started authorization cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:20,185 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) WFLYCLINF0002: Started offlineClientSessions cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:20,185 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) WFLYCLINF0002: Started offlineSessions cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:20,185 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) WFLYCLINF0002: Started actionTokens cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:20,200 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 51) WFLYCLINF0002: Started keys cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:20,200 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) WFLYCLINF0002: Started work cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:20,200 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) WFLYCLINF0002: Started loginFailures cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:20,325 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) WFLYCLINF0002: Started authenticationSessions cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:20,325 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 53) WFLYCLINF0002: Started users cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:20,325 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 47) WFLYCLINF0002: Started clientSessions cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:23,258 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) KC-SERVICES0001: Loading config from standalone.xml or domain.xml
2017-12-19 16:48:25,934 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYCLINF0002: Started realmRevisions cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:25,950 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYCLINF0002: Started userRevisions cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:25,997 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) WFLYCLINF0002: Started authorizationRevisions cache from keycloak container
2017-12-19 16:48:25,997 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) Node name: win-3n1he53opph, Site name: null
2017-12-19 16:48:30,438 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) Initializing database schema. Using changelog META-INF/jpa-changelog-master.xml
2017-12-19 16:48:32,696 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
 name: keycloak-default
 ...]
2017-12-19 16:48:32,913 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.1.10.Final}
2017-12-19 16:48:32,921 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-12-19 16:48:32,931 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-12-19 16:48:33,068 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-12-19 16:48:33,522 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-12-19 16:48:33,556 WARN  [org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) HHH000431: Unable to determine H2 database version, certain features may not work
2017-12-19 16:48:33,686 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 55) Envers integration enabled? : true
2017-12-19 16:48:35,004 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool --
```

This is the standalon print from the wilfly. 
Does this help more ? I don't know how i can connect...
FULL Log : https://plnkr.co/UybtGtz1XMTeW5774mS9

[fail on browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVmr8.png)

Comment: Posting the startup log from your wildfly might help

Comment: i add it, i hope it will help

Comment: The log looks truncated. Are you sure this is all of it? Also, are you able to connect from the server itself (using localhost as the server name)?

Comment: yes as localhost i cann connect to 8080 port, yes its truncated, stackoverflow does not allow more text , one minute, i added a plunkr url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JBoss WildFly: Starts but can't connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907323/jboss-wildfly-starts-but-cant-connect)

Answer (score 0):

By event log Undertow listen on `127.0.0.1:8080`, which is local interface.

Try to use following to start wildfly listening on all network interfaces:

```
bin/standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0
```

If it will not work, it will be firewall configuration problem.

Parameter above affects public ports only. To open management too use:

```
bin/standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0
```

Check following blogpost for more info: [Bind WildFly to a different IP address, or all addresses on multihomed](http://blog.arungupta.me/bind-wildfly-different-ip-address-multihomed/)